# How to understand the Z2 invariant in three dimensional topological insulators

Tags: topological-insulators

I know how the $Z_2$ invariant comes into the 2 dimensional topological insulator with time reversal symmetry. But I don't understand why we need to use four $Z_2$ invariant to describe the 3 dimensional topological insulator? Can anyone give me an explanation? Thanks